# Reading file contents from another directory?

Tags: php, php-7.4

I am trying to read the contents of a file in a subdirectory

**here is my attempt :**

```
$entityBody = "123456"
$vval= file_get_contents(__DIR__."/../data/names/$entityBody");
echo("$vval");
```

**here is the directory outlook:**
[image]

**Issue**: issue is when i run the script `echo("$vval");` it doesnt echo anything on the screen.
what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If `__DIR__` is evaluating to `myData` then your leading `/../` is going to traverse up, not down.

Comment: that fixed my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

In your PHP script you will see something like

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/var/www/html/myData/../data/names/123456):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Now since both your PHP script and `data` dir are sharing the same `__DIR__` you don't need `..`

So

```
$vval = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/data/names/$entityBody");
```

Will solve the problem for you.